# Why is bin(x).count('1') faster than x &= x-1?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, count, binary

Picture of code => https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQIKl.png

This algorithm is for counting the number of set bits (bits equal to 1) in a binary number.

I thought that bitwise ops would be faster, because casting a number to string then counting '1's sounds a lot slower.

```
def counting1(num):
    count = 0
    while num:
         num &= num-1
         count += 1
    return count   

def counting2(num):
    return bin(num).count('1')
```

Comment: Someone else can give a more complete answer, but the response to questions like this is usually "Because years and years of development and refinement means that, in almost all cases, the built-in types and methods are optimized, usually in C, to maximize efficiency"

Comment: My guess is the reassignment is really costly while string search for 1 is less expensive.

Comment: How big are the `num`s you tested, and what is their population count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests (`Python 3.6` on Ubuntu):

```
import timeit

for n in [0, 1, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 53, 100, 500, 10**5, 10**10, 10**50]:
    assert counting_1(n) == counting_2(n)
    t1 = timeit.timeit('f(n)', 'from __main__ import counting_1 as f, n')
    t2 = timeit.timeit('f(n)', 'from __main__ import counting_2 as f, n')
    print('{:10.4f} {:10.4f} | best {} | n {}'.format(
        t1,
        t2,
        '1' if t1 < t2 else '2',
        n))
```

The results are:

```
0.0930     0.2469 | best 1 | n 0
0.1616     0.2590 | best 1 | n 1
0.1655     0.2606 | best 1 | n 2
0.2320     0.2682 | best 1 | n 20
0.2929     0.2663 | best 2 | n 21
0.2934     0.2681 | best 2 | n 22
0.3715     0.2696 | best 2 | n 23
0.2331     0.2670 | best 1 | n 24
0.2939     0.2680 | best 2 | n 25
0.2915     0.2663 | best 2 | n 26
0.3766     0.2738 | best 2 | n 27
0.3723     0.2684 | best 2 | n 53
0.2926     0.2692 | best 2 | n 100
0.5247     0.2739 | best 2 | n 500
0.5335     0.2935 | best 2 | n 100000
0.9223     0.3147 | best 2 | n 10000000000
4.4814     0.5307 | best 2 | n 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

The speed diference probably has to do with the fact that built-in classes are implemented in C and usually outperform pure python solutions.

For small numbers `counting_1()` is faster, probably because of the overhead of converting the number that is done in `counting_2()`; but apparently for large numbers this overhead is negligible.

Note: the actual duration depends on the number of `1` that are present, and for numbers between 20 and 30 in my tests the 2 functions are very on par, but for larger numbers the native C implementation always wins.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!